# Ecologically Correct Land Fish

Tags: creature-design, environment, mythical-creatures, anatomy, ecology

The land fish is a species of fish that is, as the name implies, fully terrestrial. Their anatomy is still fish-like, though. Specifically, they have a wide head like a monkfish, with the mouth on the upper surface. They have 2 'feet' coming off the side of their throat, which they use to move. The rest of their body is thick, roughly like a goby without the tail fin, and is used to slither along the ground

It is found in West Asia, and is approximately 2ft long as an adult

This strange fish seems rather unique overall, and so it is hard to see how they'd fit into their environment

What niche in its environment could this land fish fill?

Comment: Struggling some with “west Asia”.   Hopefully not the Tarim basin.  That is hard country for a land fish.

Comment: @Willk -- "West Asia" could be Siberia, Georgia or Turkey!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Marine toad style!**

[image: marine toad]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qz_pqJd6vI

Bufo marinus gets bad press in its role as the Australian cane toad.  In Bermuda however they fit right in.  They get really big.  They eat a lot of cockroaches.  Nothing eats them because they are poisonous.

So too your land fish.  It lumbers around and eats bugs, slugs, carrion, fallen fruit, worms - it is basically a catfish as regards its tastes.  It has poisonous slime like the toad, and also spikes like a catfish so nothing much bothers the land fish.

Except ticks.  It struggles with the ticks.